# MySQL - Index Optimisation - Users associated with game

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have a table called games (unique by an int).

I have a table called members (unique by username).

In each game, a maximum of 6 members can be involved at one time.

However, a member can resign from a game - BUT I still need to keep a record they had been involved in that game.

I need to do the following separate searches:

1. Active games for a member.
2. Resigned games for a member.
3. Searches in games for an empty slot (ie a place not filled by a member).

What would be the best table structure for this?
Should I put a text field in for a member with a list of all resigned games separated by a comma? (A problem I can see with this is I will ultimately need the games information for these games, so I will subsequently need to do a separate search on the games table for each of these game numbers. That seems really slow work for the server.)

In games, should I have 6 text fields, eg SLOT1, SLOT2 etc with the present player's username? But again, what about resigned members?

NOW THE MAIN PART OF MY QUESTION (which caused all the confusion above):

How would I set up my indexes on my tables?

When I am doing searches, I will be looking in games looking at the SLOTS1, etc to see if there are any matches with a player's username. So this is an 6 times ORed search. What do I do to optimise the indexes on the database for these actions?

Then depending on how I do the resigned members for each game, how do I do an index then?

Comment: How about if you start by using an integer primary key (instead of username which is most probably a string) for your members?

Comment: I can see this will help with only needing an int in SLOTS1, etc, which would probably be quicker in the searching. However, surely the main issue with Indexes would not be resolved with just doing that.

Comment: Of course it is not THE solution but surely an important issue to be addressed. You see it matters if your primary key is data independent. If a member changes his username for any reason, then the whole index should be rearranged which in a big database is quite an overload. So it is not just string vs int issue.

Comment: Thanks Jermin. I can see your point. Updating my members table immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cross-reference table. This is a table with three columns, `game` (a foreign key to table `games`), `user` (a foreign key to table `users`), and `player_number` (a nullable integer between 1 and 6, to indicate which "seat" is occupied by the player; null indicates that the player resigned). (Variations are possible on this depending on exactly how your game works and how you want stuff to fit together, but the main thing is that you have foreign keys to `games` and `users`.)

The primary key in the above suggestion would be `(game, user, player_number)` or `(user, game, player_number)` at your convenience.

It is much easier (both for you and for your database) to search a cross-reference table like this than it is to do a query that involves ORing across six columns.

It is probably a good idea to switch to an integer primary key for the `users` table, as suggested by @Jermin Bazazian.

Comment: Never heard of foreign keys before. Just read them up. They sound great.

Comment: BTW - if I have a foreign key, does this automatically act as an index for fast lookup?

Comment: Foreign keys are automatically indexed.